# Several Apache2 processes running, using 100% CPU

Tags: linux, process, apache2, cpu, htop

I'm having this issue where the Apache service runs like 15 processes, using like 14% of CPU each, and I don't know how to track them. I'm using Linux in a DigitalOcean droplet, and I have like 6 sites enabled (some WordPress ones).

I already disabled some of the sites in order to find out which one is causing the problem, but I can't find anything. Is there any way to find out the domain or something that is creating the apache process?

Using `htop`, I receive this list:
[image: htop processes running]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a definite answer for what is happening but I can suggest a few things that may help you. Try using a more recent web server such as nginx. Apache has been outdated and is to some configurations insecure. It would be easier to just use that. Also there is a tool you can use it’s called Prometheus. It keeps track of what is happening to your hardware and can help you troubleshoot this problem. Also on the image you posted of htop, it’s describing the actual data being used is taking up the cpu. There’s not enough information provided to determine why this is happening. Send a screenshot of `ps -aux | grep apache2` or `ps -aux | grep www-data` then use the `strace` program to identify what is happening to the data in the process.